# AngularJS sort an objects array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to sort the next array but every time it gives me an error, I've looked for other solutions here in stack overflow but none of them seems to work.

```
$scope.builds = [build:[
    {'_id': '6384', 'name': Mock1, 'builDate': 20150302T110232},
    {'_id': '6383', 'name': Mock2, 'builDate': 20150209T130212},
    {'_id': '6382', 'name': Mock3, 'builDate': 20150103T145212}]
];
    var sorted = $scope.sortByKey($scope.builds.build[index],'builDate')
```

And this is my function:

```
    $scope.sortByKey = function (array, key) {
        return array.sort(function(a,b){
            var x = a[key] < b[key]? -1:1;
            return x;
        });
    }
```

Comment: ??? it give me an error

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this.

1) You are trying to use an array like an object

```
$scope.builds = [build:[
```

...should be...

```
$scope.builds = {build:[
```

2) `20150302T110232` is not a valid number (the `T` isn't allowed). So you need to turn those into strings (or turn them into actual Date objects, since that is what they appear to be).

3) `$scope.builds.build[index]` is an object, not an array. So, I'm guessing you meant `$scope.builds.build` instead.

```
var sorted = $scope.sortByKey($scope.builds.build[index],'builDate')
```

...should be...

```
var sorted = $scope.sortByKey($scope.builds.build,'builDate')
```

Comment: Thanks, when I fixed the error, I realized about the date.
Now the sort is working.

Answer (score 1):

**$scope.builds** is an array not an object, and **index** doesn't exist...try this:

```
$scope.builds = {build:[
    {'_id': '6384', 'name': Mock1, 'builDate': 20150302T110232},
    {'_id': '6383', 'name': Mock2, 'builDate': 20150209T130212},
    {'_id': '6382', 'name': Mock3, 'builDate': 20150103T145212}]
};
var sorted = $scope.sortByKey($scope.builds.build,'builDate')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear that this is the problem from your question, but you're declaring two levels of array at present.

Change the `$scope.builds` definition to:

```
$scope.builds = {build:[
    {'_id': '6384', 'name': Mock1, 'builDate': 20150302T110232},
    {'_id': '6383', 'name': Mock2, 'builDate': 20150209T130212},
    {'_id': '6382', 'name': Mock3, 'builDate': 20150103T145212}]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting as well that there are three values (0, 1, and -1) that can be returned from `Array.prototype.sort`. The sort evaluation needs to return the correct value or the sort will be unstable (and you may get an error).

Your sort function needs to look like this:

```
    return array.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a[key] == b[key]) { 
          return 0; 
        }

        return a[key] < b[key]? -1:1;
    });
```